# MQTT Subscriber Code

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe

I'm using Mosquitto as a broker to publish a message on a topic "Test".
When I'm running the subscriber code to retrieve the message and display the message on a different device on the same network, the message is not being displayed. I checked if the message was being published or not using the command "sudo mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.43.17 ......" on the device that hosted the Broker.
and the message had been published and successfully retrieved by the device and displayed.
The subscriber code is

```
package chat;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class MQTTSubscriber implements MqttCallback{
public MQTTSubscriber(){}

public void do1(){
    String topic= "Test";
    String broker= "tcp://192.168.43.17:1883";
    int qos=1;
    String clientId="20130326";
    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
    try {

        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
        System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
        sampleClient.setCallback(this);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        sampleClient.subscribe(topic, qos);
        sampleClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch(MqttException me) {
        System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
        System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
        System.out.println("excep "+me);
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Message Arrived: " + message);
}

public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
    System.out.println("Connection lost");
}

public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
    System.out.println("Delivery done");
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    new MQTTSubscriber().do1();
}
}
```

From what I understand any of the three functions messageArrived(), deilveryComplete() and connectionLost() are not being called. What changes should I make in my code to display the message?

Answer (score 0):

You are disconnecting and exiting as soon as you connect to the broker so the client never has time to receive any messages.

remove the following lines of code:

```
sampleClient.disconnect();
System.out.println("Disconnected");
System.exit(0);
```